# How to move the border in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a ListView in flutter to create a scoreboard. I want to seperate different contendants by a border. However this creates a problem with my current layout.

The BoxDecoration with the border looks the following:

```
return SizedBox(
  key: ValueKey(record.name),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 80,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Color(0xFFFF000000)),
      ),
    ),
    child: ListTile(
      leading: new CircleAvatar(
        radius: 35.0,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/XvoqJ6C.png"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      title: Text(record.name + ": " + record.score.toString(), style:
        new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
        ),),
```

And a picture of the layout can be seen here:

[image]

The problem, as can be seen in that the border is not inbetween the different listtiles, but behind the picture i am trying to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ListView.separated` like this :

```
ListView.separated(
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return  _buildListItem(context, snapshot[index]);    
    },
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Divider(
        height: 24.0,
        color: Colors.black26,
      );
    },

)
```

so instead of adding a border in each time,  separate your widgets using the `Divider()`

Comment: That makes sense, I have been using this before. However - where in my code would i implement this? I build my listview the following way: https://codeshare.io/29xkYB